# Hibernate one-to-one mapping

Tags: java, hibernate, mapping, one-to-one

I have one-to-one hibernate mapping between class Student and class Points:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Users")
public class Student implements IUser {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "student")
    private Points points;

    @Column(name = "type")
    private int type = getType();
    //gets and sets...



@Entity
@Table(name = "Points")
public class Points {

    @GenericGenerator(name = "generator", strategy = "foreign", parameters = @Parameter(name = "property", value = "student"))
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "generator")
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private int Id;


    @OneToOne
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
    private Student student;
    //gets and sets
```

And then i do:

```
Student student = new Student();
        student.setId(1);
        student.setName("Andrew");
        student.setPassword("Password");

        Points points = new Points();
        points.setPoints(0.99);

        student.setPoints(points);
        points.setStudent(student);

        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        session.save(student);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
```

And hibernate saves student in the table but not saves corresponding points. Is it OK? Should i save points separately?

Comment: I think you need to save `Pointer` also

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "student", cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST)
private Points points;
```

Can you try this.

Answer (score 2):

By default, no operations are cascaded in Hibernate. You should specify CascadeType on your one-to-one relationship.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to save the `Student` and the `Points` you need to use the `CascadeType` in your annotation, see here for [documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html_single/#entity-hibspec-cascade)